# SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, ubuntu, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using PHP Laravel 7.4 on Ubuntu 20.04.and trying to get data from SQL server located in windows server on another cloud.

this method was tested on my PC (Windows) and it successfully got the data from the windows server(mentioned above), But on my ubuntu server I follow the documents ubuntu 20.04 PHP 7.4
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15

I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP
> Provider: Error code 0x2746 (SQL: myquery)
> {"userId":94,"exception":"[object]
> (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 08001): SQLSTATE[08001]:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code
> 0x2746 (SQL: myquery) at
> /var/www/web-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669)

I checked the logs in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I notice this message appears every time I make a request from Ubuntu

> "An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client
> application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client
> application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request
> has failed."

Answer (score 5):

Try these steps:

1. Install sqsrv & pdo_sqlsrv extension & restart apache
2. Update & comment the mentioned line bellow in **config/database.php** sqlsrv array

   'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),

Final value of sqlsrv driver will be like this:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            // 'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

3. Hit these 2 command in command line of the project directory

   ```
     composer dump-autoload

     php artisan config:clear
   ```

Answer (score 2):

using docker with `thecodingmachine/php` 8.0, I solved this problem with editing `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` using configuration from https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1023#issuecomment-732947905

Answer (score 0):

I think I have faced similar error when using mssql with laravel. I solved it by installing and enabling the mssql php extension on the machine. Maybe it will help.

Comment: I did as you mentioned above and I'm still facing the same error. However, I checked the logs in MSSQL and I notice this message appears every time I make a request from Ubuntu "An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed."

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't enabled the TCP/IP protocol in the "Protocols for MSSQLSERVER" section of the SQL Server network configuration. After enabling it, everything ran smoothly.